# How can a nested Fragment inside of a Fragment know when it´s visible to user

Tags: android, android-fragments

This nested Fragment is loaded in a Fragment layout xml. I want it to know when the parent Fragment goes `FragmentManager.beginTransaction().show`. When the parent becomes visible the nested Fragment must do some work by itself.

I want to use the nested Fragment in many places would be good if it can now stuff like this, to take care of it´s own business.

Should I create some listener maybe and control this myself maybe?

here is the xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/history"
    android:name="com.pass.android.ui.fragments.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Comment: Can you add some code ?

Comment: When your main fragment receives the `onResume()` callback, you can tell the other fragment to do something.